# Error of too many positional arguments on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new on flutter and have been having an error of

`"Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.- Try removing the extra arguments."`

I had no idea how to solve the problem. Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function() answerQuestion;

  const Quiz(
      {required this.questions,
      required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex});

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion****(**answer['score'] as int****)**,
              answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a function with no parameter, but you pass one. For your code to work, your function must accept a positional parameter:

```
final Function(int) answerQuestion;
```

instead of

```
final Function() answerQuestion;
```

Optionally you can also work with named arguments:

```
final Function({required int score}) answerQuestion;
```

and call it like this:

```
answerQuestion(score: answer['score'] as int)
```

Answer (score -1):

your answerQuestion method expects no arguments.